# Space around article element in order to color it differently

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I've found a WordPress theme that I want to use, but the only problem is that the background color on articles is the same as the background color of the entire page. I want these two colors to be different, the background should be darker, and the article white.

Here is the current situation:

[image]

The problem is that I cannot simply set the `background-color` atribute on `article` because there is no spacing around it, and it looks bad. To demonstrate:

[image]

**Edit: the green here should be away from the text for about half a centimeter:**

[image]

The color is green just so it's easier to notice **how close it is to the article content.**

What I want to achieve is to create a spacing, between the article title, information, and content - and the background of the website. However, I also fear that **this spacing might ruing the mobile experience if it is fixed to a percentage or length**, so the real issue is creating it so that it either disappears or is not noticeable on mobile devices.

How can I do that?

If needed, here is the link to my blog: http://jancorazza.com.

Comment: what should it be like ? then

Comment: @GCyrillus Please see the edit, I've clarified what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding might be what you need :

```
.content-area article {
   background-color: green;
   padding: 25px;
}
```